# Send email from oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, email, smtp

My OS : Windows 10
DB    : Oracle 11g
Both Oracle 11g and SQL Developer installed on the same machine

I run the sqlplus as sys user.

I set all the requirements to send email.
Like

1. install utlmail.sql, prvtmail.plb and utlsmtp.sql
2. ALTER SESSION SET SMTP_OUT_SERVER = '';\

   ```
    BEGIN
      UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => 'me@gmail.com',
                    recipients => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
                    subject    => 'UTL_MAIL Test',
                    message    => 'If you get this message it worked!');
   ```

   END;
   /

But I receive the error as:

```
    BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 654
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 671
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Also I tried using ALTER SESSION SET SMTP_OUT_SERVER = 'localhost';

but not succeeded.

Any help?

Note: IIS is running on my Windows 10. But I did not see any SMTP Server there.

Advance thanks to all

Comment: You must have an e-mail (i.e. SMTP) server to submit mail to. Windows does not provide this service by default.

Comment: do I need to install SMTP server myself? Can we specify as smtp_out_server = 'smtp.gmail.com';

Comment: Not sure that Oracle would support the SSL or TLS connection to Google that would be required, which leaves you installing your own somewhere. I'm not sure that there is a free SMTP server for Windows; that's more of a Linux feature.